# How to hide elements only if viewed in an iframe

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

I want to turn off a specific element in an iframe - but show it if the map is viewed separately.

I have Google maps that I created, and they reside on the same domain, folders, etc as the site. I have control of both as far as CSS, JavaScript, etc.

I have web pages that have the map in an iframe to display with the other content that describes the map. There is a link on the webpage to view the map separately if the user wants to see just the map by itself. In the HTML document that creates the map itself, I have an element with a link that floats above the map with the logo for the site so the user can return to the website.

I don't want this logo to show when viewed with an iframe, but I do want it to show if the map is viewed by itself.

I did research this, and tried methods suggested using CSS for the page with the iframe and display: none, but somehow something wasn't working.

I don't care if it needs JavaScript, jQuery, or CSS, I just need something that works. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use some simple JavaScript to check if the page is being rendered in a frame:

```
if (window.top != window) {
    // in a frame, hide stuff
}
```

`window.top` refers to the uppermost window in the page. When the page is viewed on its own, that is the regular `window`; in a frame, it isn't.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and I just tried it again to no avail. Maybe I am just not targeting it correctly? I have it in a jQuery document ready - so I am using jQuery functions.

if (window.top != window) {
    $("#wrulogo").hide();
}

The above did not work

if (window.top != window) {
    $("#wrulogo").css("display", "none");
}

This did not work, either.

Answer (score 2):

you could detect if the `self` window is also the `top` window. If not then apply a class to the `root` element and use that class to hide or show parts of the content: if you place this script in the `head`

```
<script>
   (function(d, w) {
      if (w.self !== w.top) {
         /* this document is loaded in a frame/iframe */
         d.className += " iframe";
      }
   }(document.documentElement, window));
</script>
```

before CSS inclusion, then you may write this kind of rules

```
.map { display: block; }
.iframe .map { display: none; }
```

or use jQuery like so

```
$('.iframe .map').hide();
```

Comment: I got it to work by first having it styled display: none then adding this to the jQuery  if (window.self == window.top) {
       $("#wrulogo").show();
    }